# How to inject Service Layer into controller when service layer depends upon repository and UnitOfWork

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am a little confused about how this would work with Unity.  Let's assume the following scenario, I have a controller called TestController that depends upon two Services ServiceA and ServiceB.  Now serviceA depends upon two Repositories, RepositoryA1 and RepositoryA2.  ServiceB depends upon one Repository, RepositoryB.  Let's further assume that ServiceA, RepositoryA1 and RepositoryA2 depends upon UnitOfWork, UnitOfWork1.  I am having trouble understanding how to implement this for MVC3 and the Unity Application Block.  Could someone provide an example of how this should be coded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot opinions on this but this is how I worked it out for myself

**UnitOfWork**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    FooContext DbContext { get; }
    void Save();
}
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    protected string ConnectionString;
    private FooContext context;

    public UnitOfWork(string connectionString)
    {
        this.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public FooContext DbContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                context = new FooContext(ConnectionString);
            }
            return context;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**GenericRepository**

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> :
    IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected FooContext DbContext;

    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.DbContext = unitOfWork.DbContext;
    }

    ...
}
```

Generic repositories here but they could just as well be built to be specific.

**Service**

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private IGenericRepository<Foo> fooRepository;
    private IGenericRepository<Bar> barRepository;

    public FooService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
                      IGenericRepository<Foo> fooRepository,
                      IGenericRepository<Bar> barRepository)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.fooRepository = fooRepository;
        this.barRepository = barRepository;
    }
}
```

You still need to pass the IUnitOfWork to get access to the `Save` method. I suppose I could have gotten it from one of the repositories.

**UnityConfig**

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(ConnectionString));
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
container.RegisterType<IFooService, FooService>();
container.RegisterType<IBarService, BarService>();
```

**Controller**

```
private IFooService fooService;
private IBarSevice barService;

public HomeController(IFooService fooService, IBarService barService)
{
    this.fooService = fooService;
    this.barService = barService;
}
```

Comment: So this will automatically inject the UnitOfWork into the service and the repositories?

Comment: @user1790300 Yes, because each dependency in the chain is registered

Comment: It would be convenient to make repositories as properties (with lazy loading) of the unit of work. So, you need to pass to service one unit of work without long list of repositories.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using the HierarchicalLifetimeManager when creating the UnitOfWork?

Comment: The way I understand it: 1) Each request gets the same UoW 2) It will call dispose at the end of the request. I'm sure there is a better reference I read but here's what I found immediately http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/